Why does the remainder part of the Taylor formula contains all the remaining error of the approximation
I have a question regarding the Taylor formula.
In the Taylor formula theorem :

Let $I$ be an open interval, and $f \in C^{k+1}(I)$. Then for any $ x_0 \in I $, $f$ has a series expansion of degree $k$ around $ x_0 $, given by
$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0) + \frac{f^{(2)}(x_0)}{2!} (x - x_0)^2 + \frac{f^{(3)}(x_0)}{3!} (x - x_0)^3 + \cdots + \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!} (x - x_0)^k + R(x),
$$
where the remainder $ R(x) = (x - x_0)^k \varepsilon(x) $, and the function $ \varepsilon(x) $ is given by
$$
\varepsilon(x) = \frac{(x - x_0) f^{(k+1)}(u)}{(k + 1)!},
$$
and $ u $ is a real number between $ x_0 $ and $ x $, which depends on $ x_0, x, k, f $.

My question is how can the rest correct all the error of the approximation, why don't we need higher derivatives like $(k+2)$th derivative to correct the error of the approximation ? Why is the rest only dependent on the $(k+1)$th derivative ? What is the graphical interpretation behind this and behind the symbolic form of the remainder.
Also for example if a consider the order 1 series expansion of $f(x) = cos(x)$ at $0$ which is given by the formula above.
$$
cos(x) = cos(0) - sin(0)(x - 0) + R(x) = 1 + R(x) = 1 + x^2 \frac{cos''(u)}{2!}
$$
So the rest depends on the second derivative of $cos(x)$ at a point $u$. And if I choose a point that is far from $0$ like for example $x = 3\pi$, I don't understand graphically how the rest $R(3\pi)$ can "correct" the error which is big.
Also if we had to plot the function $1 + R(x)$ with $u$ chosen so that $cos(3\pi) = 1 + R(3\pi)$, what would it look like ? Would it have the same shape as $cos(x)$ ? If yes I don't see how this can be possible. Or does it just intersect with $cos(x)$ at $x = 3\pi$ and $x = 0$ ?
Tell me if my questions are unclear.
Thanks !

A lot of the time I think proofs, or even proof sketches, end up being more confusing than illuminating, especially for people not accustomed to them. But I think this approach to Taylor's theorem does not have this weakness. And I think it makes it clear why only the next derivative is needed. The problem with it is that it involves multiple integrals and a lot of ugly notation. Fortunately, it doesn't require any prior knowledge about multiple integrals. All it really needs is the FTC, the extreme value theorem, and the intermediate value theorem.
The gist of it is "apply the FTC a whole bunch of times":
\begin{align}
& f(x) =f(a)+\int_a^x f'(x_1) dx_1 \\
& = f(a)+\int_a^x \left ( f'(a) + \int_a^{x_1} f''(x_2) dx_2 \right ) dx_1 \\
& = f(a) + \int_a^x \left ( f'(a) + \int_a^{x_1} \left ( f''(a) + \int_a^{x_2} f'''(x_3) dx_3 \right ) dx_2 \right ) dx_1 \\
& = f(a) + \int_a^x \left ( f'(a) + \int_a^{x_1} \left ( f''(a) +  \int_a^{x_2} \left ( f'''(a) +  \int_a^{x_3} f^{(4)}(x_4) dx_4 \right ) dx_3 \right ) dx_2 \right ) dx_1
\end{align}
and the pattern continues. These integrals that involve derivatives evaluated at $a$ are not hard: change variables to $w=x-a$ and you read off the $f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k/k!$ terms.
Since the goal is the Lagrange remainder, you can work with the integral for the remainder as follows. Write $m \leq f^{(n)}(x_n) \leq M$ using the extreme value theorem. Then you can integrate these inequalities, and you find that the integral you want is between $m (x-a)^n/n!$ and $M (x-a)^n/n!$, which means it must be $f^{(n)}(u)(x-a)^n/n!$ for some $u$ by the intermediate value theorem.
Anyway, there is not much of a graphical interpretation of the Lagrange remainder as an exact equation. There is one for the Lagrange remainder as a bound. For example for $\cos$ with $n=1$, that interpretation is that $\cos(x)$ is between $1-x^2/2$ and $1+x^2/2$, but that's all. There is no real graphical interpretation for $-\cos(u(x)) x^2/2$ itself, because that's just going to be $\cos(x)-1$ by how $u$ was defined. The fact that it is written differently doesn't change what it is.

The answer is that the remainder term includes an extra variable - $u$ in your examples, which itself depends on $x$, so it is able to take the place of all of the behaviour of those higher derivatives. The important part is that because of the way $u$ depends on $x$, it still provides a bounding value for the remainder.
Looking at $\cos x$, for example, knowing that $\cos u$ must be between $-1$ and $1$ means that $1 - \frac{x^2}{2} \leq \cos x \leq 1 + \frac{x^2}{2}$. And if we graph those functions, that's pretty clearly true.
What you'll notice, though, is that those parabolas do not provide a great approximation for $\cos x$ outside of a fairly tight interval, and that's because $\cos x$ is bounded but $x^2$ gets big. If we add more terms to the Taylor polynomial things get better in some places but even worse out at the edges - you can see this in the graphs of the residuals where things flatten out to zero in the middle but blow out at the edges. We have ways to describe this, using terms like "interval of convergence" and "uniform versus pointwise convergence".

Thanks for your answer ! I just don't really understand this sentence : "The important part is that because of the way $u$
depends on $x$, it still provides a bounding value for the remainder." Could you elaborate more on that ?
Also would the plot of $1 + R(x)$ with $u$ chosen so that $cos(3\pi) =1 + R(3\pi)$ would look like this : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l47odk0ho5
I want to be sure that the way I see the formula graphically is correct
Thanks !

@rory Strictly speaking, $R(3\pi)=2$, so $-\cos(u(3\pi))=4/(9\pi^2) \approx 0.045$, yes. But I wouldn't really take that visualization very seriously; what $R(x)$ actually looks like is literally $\cos(x)-1$, that's what it is. What is helpful in the Lagrange remainder is that we can say $\cos(x)-1=-\cos(u(x)) x^2/2$ for some $u$ between $0$ and $x$, which gives us a better-than-trivial bound for it if $x$ is not too big.

@Ian thanks for your answer it made the whole a lot clearer! I was wondering when we write $cos(x) - 1 = -cos(u(x)) \frac{x^2}{2}$ we imply that for each $x$ the right hand side will change right ? Like graphically it would be for each $x$ we change the factor before $\frac{x^2}{2}$ so that this function intersect with $cos(x) - 1$ ?

@rory Right; so for $f=\cos$, $R(x)=\cos(x)-1$ everywhere, and we are only writing that in a different way.

Thank you @Ian!

It might help to think about Taylor's remainder theorem when $k=0$. Start from the mean value for derivatives: when $f$ is a nice enough function there will always be a point $c$ between $a$ and $b$ where the slope is the same as the slope of the secant:
$$
f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} .
$$
That's easy to see in a picture, and often the first step in the proof of Taylor's theorem.
If you rearrange that with $b = x$ and $a=x_0$
you see
$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + (x-x_0)f'(c).
$$
Thus the error in the approximation when $k=0$ is
$$
\epsilon(x) = (x-x_0)f'(c)
$$
for some $c$ between $x$ and $x_0$. Of course you don't know exactly where $c$ is. But if you know (somehow) that the derivative is bounded, so that
$$
|f'(x)| < M
$$
everywhere, then you can use the remainder theorem to bound the change in $f$:
$$
|f(x) - f(x_0)| < M|x-x_0)|.
$$

Let $\mathcal C^k_I$ denote the space of $k$-times continuously differentiable functions on an open interval $I\subseteq \mathbb R$. Suppose that $f\in \mathcal C^k_I$ and $a \in I$. We let the $k$-th Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $a$ to be the polynomial of degree $k$ given by
$$
P_{k,a}(f)(x) := \sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{f^{(j)}(a)}{j!}(x-a)^j
$$
and set $E_{k,a}(f) := f-P_{k,a}(f)(x)$ to be the "error" in approximating $f$ by $P_{k,a}(f)$.
$P_{k,a}(f)$ and $E_{n,a}(f)$ therefore together determine $f$ and conversely of course, $f$ determines $P_{k,a}(f)$ and so $E_{k,a}(f)$. The various forms of Taylor's theorem seek to describe the error term $E_{k,a}(f)$. The form of the remainder explicitly mentioned in the OP is that due to Lagrange, and it asserts that, if $f\in \mathcal C^{(k+1)}_I$ then
$$
E_{k,a}(f)(x) = \frac{f^{(k+1)}(\xi)}{(k+1)!}(x-a)^{k+1}.
$$
But while the right-hand side gives an expression for the error, it is not the case that $\xi$ is a function of $x$ - in general it is not unique, and what the expression really says is just that the value of $\frac{(k+1)!}{(x-a)^{k+1}}E_{n,a}(f)(x)$ lies in the image of the open interval $I_{a,x}$ between $a$ and $x$ (so either $(a,x)$ or $(x,a)$ depending on which is larger) under the function $f^{(k+1)}$. Thus it is in fact only a bound on the value of $E_{n,a}(f)(x)$.
However, the question seems to ask why $E_{k,a}(f)$ should be expressible only in terms of $f^{(k+1)}(x)$ and not require the higher derivatives of $f$. But if $f \colon I \to \mathbb R$ is a function on an open interval $I$ and $f \in \mathcal C^k_I$, then $f',f^{(2)},\ldots,f^{(k)}$ are all uniquely determined by $f$. Thus "knowledge of $f$" determines all of its derivatives on $I$ also. On the other hand, the fundamental theorem of calculus shows us that if we know $f(a)$ and $f'$ on $I$, we can recover $f$ via
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
f(x)= f(a)+\int_{a}^x f'(t)dt
$$
and hence iterating, if we know $f(a),\ldots,f^{(k-1)}(a)$ and $f^{(k)}(x)$ on $I$ then we can recover $f$ (and also all $f^{(r)}(x)$ for $1\leq r<k$). Thus knowledge of the derivatives of a function is always strictly less information than knowledge of the function itself. From that perspective, the question of why one does not need higher derivatives of $f$ to express the error term has the obvious answer that they carry less information! (Another, more pedantic, point that might be made is that the various forms of Taylor's theorem usually only require $f$ to be $k$ or $k+1$ times differentiable, thus $f^{(k+2)}$ may not even exist!)
It might help to consider the asymptotic version Taylor's theorem, which is only requires the function $f$  to be $(k-1)$-times differentiable on $I$ and in addition that $f^{(k)}(a)$ exists.
To state it we first need some notation. If $g\colon I \to \mathbb R$ then we write, for $m\in \mathbb Z_{>0}$, $g \in o((x-a)^m)$ if $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{g(x)}{(x-a)^m} =0$. Informally we say that $g$ vanishes at $a$ to order at least $m$. Notice that, since the function $(x-a)^{-m}$ is smooth on $\mathbb R\backslash \{a\}$, the function $g(x)/(x-a)^m$ is $r$-times differentiable if $f$ is, thus if $g \in \mathcal C^{r}_I$ and $g \in o((x-a)^m)$ then $g=(x-a)^mg_1(x)$ where $g_1(x) \in \mathcal C^{r}_I$, and hence $g \in o((x-a)^m))$ if and only if $g\in (x-a)^m \mathcal C^{r}_I$, that is $g$ is in the ideal of the ring $\mathcal C^{r}_I$ generated by $(x-a)^m$.
The asymptotic version of Taylor's theorem then asserts that the Taylor polynomials form an ``asymptotic expansion'' of $f$ at $a$, in that for any $f \in \mathcal C^{k-1}_I$ such that $f^{(k)}(a)$ exists, we have
$$
E_{k,a}(f) = f(x)- P_{k,a}(f)(x) \in o((x-a)^k),
$$
Notice that any polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $k$ can be written in the form $\sum_{j=0}^k c_j (x-a)^j$ and thus clearly $p(x)$ is in $o((x-a)^k)$ if and only if $p(x)$ is identically zero. Thus this form of Taylor's theorem shows that $P_{k,a}(f)(x)$ is the unique degree $k$ polynomial such that the error in approximating $f$ by $P_{k,a}(f)$ goes to $0$ faster than $(x-a)^k$ as $x$ tends to $a$. Since $g \in o((x-a)^m)$ certainly implies that $g \in o((x-a)^r)$ for all $r\leq m$, the theorem shows that the sequence of Taylor polynomials $P_{m,a}(f)$ give better and better asymptotic approximations to $f$ at $a$. Notice that if you assume that $f$ is in $\mathcal C^k_I$ then this result follows from a repeated application of ($\dagger$), but the result holds for all $f \in \mathcal C^{k-1}_I$ for which $f^{(k)}(a)$ exists.
On the other hand, one might also ask the question of whether knowledge of only the values $f^{(k)}(a)$ of the higher derivatives of $f$ at $a$ for all $k \geq 0$, which is equivalent to knowing all of the Taylor polynomials of $f$ at $a$, gives you enough information to recover $f$, at least on some open interval centred at $a$ say. The answer to this question is "no", as examples such as
$$
g(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} \exp(-\frac{1}{x}), &  x > 0, \\
0, & x \leq 0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
show.
